# Can I add a foreign key to already existing table with data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am wondering if I can add a foreign key to an already existing table with records in it.

The tables structure and the data in it looks like that at the moment:

Books table:

```
ID | BookName | BookCode | BookEdition | AuthorID
1  |  Name1   |   Code1  |     1       |    1
2  |  Name1   |   Code1  |     2       |    2
```

Authors table:

```
ID | AuthorName
1  |  Name1 
2  |  Name2
```

Basically, I want to add link the two tables based on the `AuthorID`, the problem is that the column already has data in it, as shown in the example above, but these ids are the correct ones and they also exist in the `Authors` table.

Is it possible to do that without re-creating the tables?

Comment: Did you try it? Of course you can add a foreign key when there is data...assuming you don't have any values that violate the new constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `alter table`:

```
alter table books add constraint fk_books_authorid
    foreign key (AUthorId) references Authors(ID);
```